# is it possible to specify android:minHeight to be the same as android:layout_width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `xml` layout file for a venue details page, which specifies a few linear layouts and then a map view. Each linear layout has 2 `TextViews`, one as a header and another as the detail. At the bottom of the page is a `mapView` which shows the location of the venue.

On a large screen/tablet the map has plenty of room and looks fine, on a smaller screen, e.g. on a phone the map is squeezed into this tiny space at the bottom of the screen.
I'm happy with main layout of the page except for the map at the bottom.

What I would like to do is to specify that the minimum height of the map is at least the same `dp` as the available width - i.e. *make sure its square*. If there is more space for the map to fill at the bottom of the screen - i.e. to make it a portrait aspect rectangle, then it should do so.

Edit : I don't want to reduce the already dynamic size of the `LinearLayouts` as the information they provide is actually what the user will want to see.

pseudo code below:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="android:layout_width"
    />
```

I can see that it would be possible to do this through `Java` code. I can also see that I would be able to set a specific size such as `320dp`, but this then requires more effort to get the size correct for multiple screen sizes.

Is this possible in `xml` alone?

Comment: You could use a linear layout and always assign 50% of the screen height to the MapView? Infact, you can vary the percentage to give the MapView by screen size and dpi.

Comment: Thanks @confused_at_times, the idea is a good one but the information provided by the `LinearLayout`s further up the page is where the real information of the page is and so it doesn't make sense to reduce the available size of those to display the map.

Comment: For me as a user, I'd probably want my map to be in a fixed position with full width of the screen real estate (in portrait mode). Any other info can be put elsewhere with a ScrollView if required. The map is the eye-grabber really, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had time to think about the comments made by @confused_at_times, I decided that in fact the problem was in the layout of my activity and not in the unavailable option in the xml.

My chosen solution is to have the map as the main element of the page with the marker pin being clickable and showing all available detail upon click.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in XML for most `View` types.

As you know it can be accomplished in code, but I have always thought this type of a feature would be very helpful.

---

However for an `ImageView` you can accomplish something like this using the `adjustViewBounds` property, for example if you want a banner image at the top of your screen, and you want it to size correctly.

This XML below shows how to use that property:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/big_image" />
```

First impression is that this image will `match_parent` in both height & width i.e. fill the screen. The `scaleType` will allow it to change size if required.

The trick is using `adjustViewBounds` set to `true`.

The image is scaled, but the bottom bound of the view is brought up to `wrap_content` of the newly scaled image.

Bear in mind that this method will not stretch a smaller image, but will work when shrinking a larger image onto a smaller screen.